# How can one monitor the HTTP traffic generated by docker push with Fiddler on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, fiddler

I have a problem - the build server is unable to push a docker image. All the layers were pushed, except one which fails with EOF.

I want to understand what HTTP traffic `docker push` generates.

Here is what I have done:

1. All the necessary actions to capture HTTPS as explained in https://samcogan.com/capturing-terraform-azure-cli-traffic-with-fiddler/ As a result I can see the Azure CLI traffic.
2. I set the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables to **http://localhost:8888**

But this is not enough for `docker push`, so the question is - what needs to be done for Fiddler to be able to intercept docker push HTTP traffic?

Answer (score 0):

I understood my problem. `docker` CLI is a client - I knew that. But I thought that pushing an image is done by that client, not the service.

Well, I was wrong. It is the service all the way. So, `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` must be set in the environment of the service. The build server does not have the Docker Desktop where these can be set in the GUI. Instead, it runs the dockerd.exe service. So, I must make sure the service is started from the context having these environment variables.